# Can we pick a cheaper starting ship and add mods to it at the start?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

Can a group pick a cheap ship with mods as a starting ship in EotE, as long as the total cost doesn't exceed the 120.000 maximum credit amount for starting ships?

Comment: Hi Nyllcode, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. I see from your Informed badge you've already checked out our [tour]; thanks for doing that. If you have any site about the site itself or how to use it you can ask on [meta], and whenever you reach 20 rep you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 6):

### It's up to your GM

The rules say that the group starts with a ship with a cost of up to 120,000 credits, but not that you have 120,000 credits to spend on a ship and it's accessories.

> As part of their Obligation, each group starts the game **with a starship**. This is the final part of character creation. The GM can choose one of these three ships as his group's starter vessel. Alternatively, experienced groups can select their own ship, so long as that ship costs no more than 120,000 credits and is approved by the GM.

So the players start with one of three possible ships presented by the book, or pick their own ship as long as it doesn't cost more than 120,00 credits. But makes no mention of modifications or equipment inside the ship.

However, as *long as that ship costs no more than 120,000 credits and is **approved by the GM*** you can start with any ship you want.

The GM has the final say on what ship your group starts with, he has [all the power to](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleZero) allow or disallow a specific ship. If you check *Age of Rebellion* (p. 111), characters are presented with three different options instead of a single ship worth 120,000 credits:

- A stolen imperial *Lambda* Shuttle, which is worth 140,000 credits;
- A *Y-Wing* squadron, worth 80,000 **each**. Yes, that's right, one Y-Wing for every two members of the group (four PCs = two y-wings);
- A base of operations, which has no listed value but will grant an additional 1,000 worth of gear for every PC. This can be expanded by the supplements published, though;

With that said, when I ran my first *Edge of Empire* campaign, set in the *Old Republic*, the players didn't start with a ship at all, but ended the second session stealing a [Pathfinder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pathfinder-class_scout_ship), a ship worth 135,000 credits.

Comment: I don't see how the quoted text disallows mods. The mods would be part of the ship, they're not "accessories". If I buy a car with built-in GPS, that just adds to the value, it doesn't mean I bought a car and a GPS.

Comment: @Theik, modifications are *vastly* different from built-in GPS. They are more like stuff you add to your car *after* you bought it. A GPS would be part of the factory mods, and many ships already come with installed weapons, or better engines, heavier armor plating, or even stealth technology, those aren't installed by the user, they are *built-in*.

Comment: A YT1300 comes with many "open" mod slots because its a big ship made for transporting cargo, when you install additional weapons, you are using that space for a new purpose not intended by the designer. There are many ships that come with fewer (or no) hard points for modifications, but that is made up by all the systems that come installed on it.